# Exercice with scan files

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have to print the even lines of this file "text", how can I do that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File f =new File("text.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `if (lineNumber % 2 == 0)` then it is an even numbered line. You just need a counter variable or some way to keep track of how many lines you have looked at so far.

Comment: It is really simple to do it using '%', the point is to try it yourself, as of being an excercise. You just need to add 2-3 lines of code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy way to keep track of which line you are on and how to tell if it is an even number or not. If it is indeed an even number, then we print it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File f = new File("text.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
    int counter = 1; //This will tell you which line you are on

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        if (counter % 2 == 0) { //This checks if the line number is even
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        counter++; //This says we just looked at one more line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [remainder operator %](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#d5e27634) on the line number while iterating over the file contents

Answer (score 0):

You can also just consume two tokens per iteration of the while loop and print out every first (even) one.

Using a counter is probably clearer though.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class NumberPrinter {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File f =new File("text.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
      if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        scanner.nextLine();
      }
    }
  }
}
```